# WPF WindowsFormsHost memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, windowsformshost

I've got a WPF TabControl containing a WindowsFormsHost in each TabPage.
User can add and remove TabPage as needed: when the user removes a Tab, I obviously dispose the child control and the host itself.

Using VS Diagnostic Tool, I've found a leak of WindowsFormsHost:

[image: leak]

I've also reproduced the issue using an empty WindowsFormsHost, with no inner child, tested with framework 4.0 and 4.7.2. Something like:

```
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost/>
```

How can I solve? GC.Collect() does not do the trick.

Comment: What specifically makes this a "leak"?  Maybe the garbage collector just hasn't collected it yet.

Comment: Leak because after 15/20 minutes that memory should be released...

Comment: Maybe. You should add some garbage collection calls just for debugging purposes to see if that causes the memory to be released or not. If it does not, I agree that sounds like a leak. But if it DOES get released, then its just a case of the GC taking its time.  e.g. you will want to add something like `  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();` ...

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs no way, still there

Comment: That's good info. I think you should edit the question with the code you used to test this.

Answer (score 3):

Solved removing the WindowsFormsHost element from parent layout:

```
public class WindowsFormsHostEx : WindowsFormsHost
{
    public WindowsFormsHostEx() { }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (this.Child != null && this.Child is IDisposable)
            (this.Child as IDisposable).Dispose();

        this.Child = null;

        //magic line!!!
        (this.Parent as Panel).Children.Remove(this);

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but this fix did not work for me :(